# HTML 5 Required Stays Required

Tags: html, forms, validation

I have a form that has a checkbox set as required:

```
<input required="required" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Este campo es requerido')" type="checkbox" name="terms" value="Si Acepto" />
```

Initially, after the page loads and I hit submit (without clicking on the checkbox), the required attribute triggers correctly. I then click the checkbox and hit SUBMIT again, but the required attribute still triggers, it doesn't recognise that the checkbox has been checked and the required attribute has been fulfilled.

This is probably a very simple problem but how do I fix this?

Comment: That code runs well for me. The form submits correct with that line.

Comment: @Gonzalo the issue is with it being submitted wrong once you can't rectify it without refreshing the page

Comment: I add that to a form. I tired to submit and the message alerted me. The I click the checkbox and resubtmit the form and it worked

Comment: @Gonzalo read below for the root of the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"` as attribute to your checkbox. Since you set it to invalid once it will stay at this state! But when you reset the validation every time you change the value it works.

```
<input required="required" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Este campo es requerido')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')" type="checkbox" name="terms" value="Si Acepto" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much this works - don't understand what the problem was though, but thanks.

Comment: As I wrote above. You set the checkbox to invalid by this attribute `oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Este campo es requerido')"` this will never change back to valid until you do this by your own e.g. with this attribute `onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"` everytime the value of the checkbox changes